# Default size for all pyplot charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a notebook with several plots where I have at the very beginning the following code:

```py
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 9]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100
```

So that all the charts generated in the notebook have this size. This just **stopped working** (I suppose after the last pip update) and now all the charts have a different default size (much smaller).

How can I set now the default size for all my pyplot charts?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was behaviour was changed deliberately.  One thing that does reset the size is `%matplotlib inline`; I always put my `plt.rcParams` size override *after* that.  Could you give a minimal working example?  The code from a single-celled notebook showing the problem would be ideal.  Also please tell us what versions of Matplotlib and Jupyter you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Rory, you are right.

Somehow I missed the `%matplotlib inline` magic function before settings the properties of the plot. So this is what is working for me now:

```py
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 9]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100
```

Thanks!